# Распознавание речи

Tags: java, алгоритм, аудио, распознавание-речи

Привет всем пользователям ХэшКода.

Очень заинтересовался недавно работой таких систем, как распознавание речи.
Штука о-ооочень сложная, но в то же время и интересная.

Всегда задавался вопросом, когда нажимал на микрофончик от компании гуглъ: какой путь проходит наш голос от нажатия, собственно, на микрофончик, до появления текста в строке?

Возможно вы скажите: "Да нет, это уж слишком..."

Но тема действительно интересная.
Так как работаю я в основном с языком — Java, то и экспериментировать буду с ним.

Полной информации по этой теме мало, но кое что есть:

1. [Распознавание речи от Яндекса. Под капотом у Yandex.SpeechKit](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/198556/) — cтатья Яндекса о том, как устроен Yandex.SpeechKit.
2. [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) — достаточно интересная библиотека, написанная как раз на Java.
3. Всё, что связано со звуком на сайте [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Звук](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA)
4. [Распознавание речи. Часть 1. Классификация систем распознавания речи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64572/) — статья с хабра (точнее цикл статей), довольно интересно почитать.
5. [Распознавание речи. Часть 2. Типичная структура системы распознавания речи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64594/) — цикл статей, продолжение, взято с хабра.
6. [Распознавание речи. Часть 3. Голосовой тракт, слуховой тракт](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64681/) — последняя статья из цикла.
7. [Дискретное преобразование Фурье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) — статья из википедии, достаточно интересная.
8. [OpenSource Java Math Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227105526/http://habrahabr.ru/post/102603) — вот интересная весч, так как пишу на Java.
9. [Синтез и распознавание речи. Современные решения](http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/hi/index.html) — стоит почитать (на титл страницы не обращайте внимания).
10. [Распознавание речи с помощью CMU Sphinx](https://habrahabr.ru/post/267539/) — приведен пример распознавание русской речи.

Недавно посмотрел лекции некоего *Малого ШАД,а* — было бы интересно увидеть материалы по данной тематике. Как раз на примере *Яндекс SpeechKit*.

Для начала сойдёт).

(Предлагайте свои ссылки в ответах/комментариях)

Итак, зачем же я создал этот вопрос о том, как всё же устроены эти системы?

Примерно представление у меня такое:
Записывается звук → Анализируется, составляется его спектр, с помощью некоего алгоритма *дискретного косинусного преобразования* мы получаем некий вектор MFCC, в общем раскладываем/анализируем звук и сравниваем полученный анализ с неким словарём).

В общем предлагайте свои задумки по данной тематике).
Может кто-то "баловался" и хотел писать что-то подобное)?

Конечно, можно с лёгкостью написать код, который будет соединяться с серверами Google и выдавать текст, но ведь это не так интересно).

Заранее благодарю! Да прибудет с нами сила звука!

Некий концепт уже мне понятен, осталось сформировать его и выложить здесь).

**UPD**

Обновил, добавил пару ссылок.

Comment: Предлагайте свои идеи по данной теме! свои задумки как там все устроено,интересно ведь) ссылки..

Comment: > Распознавание речи. Часть 2. Типичная структура системы распознавания речи
> (цикл статей,продолжение,взято с хабра)
Там изображения потерялись, вот копия статьи вместе со схемами
http://www.intellect25.com/?p=676